# Problem with mailutils, ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, postfix, mail, mailutils

Can someone help me about this problem, I've tried to find out where the problem is comming from, but have no luck, I've tried to re-install postfix and mailutils, but still have this problem, if someone can help me, please reply, I've been stuck with this problem for over 2.5 hrs now!

```
carl@carlium:~$ sudo echo "This email confirms that Postfix is working" | mail -s "Testing Posfix" <mymail>@outlook.com
mail: Unknown command: account
mail: Unknown command: }
mail: Sending data to /usr/bin/msmtp failed: Cannot execute
mail: cannot send message: Cannot execute
```

Comment: You Do NOT need `sudo` to `echo`. If you really put `<` and `>` around `mymail`, you've redirected input from `mymail` and redirected the output to `@outlook.com`.

Comment: I didn't put <> there, those was just for indicating that I used an another name, I also tried without sudo, it didn't work anyways. I'm re-installing ubuntu now and see if that changes something, I've tried so many ways via different websites and none of them worked, I've probably installed to many things that collide with each other too.

Answer (score 0):

Try fix ~/.mailrc like follow

```
set smtp-use-starttls
set ssl-verify=ignore
set smtp=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587
set smtp-auth=login
set smtp-auth-user=$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS
set smtp-auth-password=$EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
set from="$FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS($FRIENDLY_NAME)"
```

[How to Send Email from mailx/s-nail Command in Linux Using Gmail’s SMTP](https://www.systutorials.com/sending-email-from-mailx-command-in-linux-using-gmails-smtp/)